# Yup - input field as integer, postive and allowing 0 - comma in the number is not treated as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have the following:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
    closedBugs: yup
      .number()
      .typeError("Please enter a valid number")
      .integer("Please enter an integer")
      .required("This field is required")
      .test(
        "is-positive",
        "Please enter a positive number",
        (value) => value >= 0 && 1 / value !== -Infinity
      ),
  });
```

Which works fine, I get the expected validation messages for everything that is not a positive integer (allowing 0).
But this is strange to me:
If I input -45.1 (with dot) I get the messages:

```
Please enter an integer
Please enter a positive number
```

But if I enter -45,1 (with comma) I get the message:

```
Please enter a valid number
```

Why is this treated differently and is there a way to make it behave as the input -45.1 (the one with the dot)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by modifying the value in the react-hook-forms:

```
               <input
                  {...register("closedBugs", {
                    setValueAs: modifyBugsValues,
                  })}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
                  name="closedBugs"
                  placeholder="1"
                  required
                />
```

Where the `modifyBugsValues` is:

```
const modifyBugsValues = (value) => {
    if (value === "") {
      // needed in order for yup to return required field validation in case of empty field
      return undefined;
    } else {
      // needed in order for yup to treat 1,2 as 1.2 and return integer validation
      value = value.replace(/,/g, ".");
      return value;
    }
  };
```

Not sure if there is some better way of doing it :D